# Stringify object differently depending on context

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have an object with a toJSON method:

```
const v = {
  foo: 'zoom1',
  bar: 'zoom2',
  toJSON(){
     return {foo: this.foo}
  }
}
```

when I call `JSON.stringify(v)` I will get `{foo:'zoom1'}` - my question is - is there a way to stringify it differently depending on who is calling JSON.stringify(), for example, what if I want:

```
{bar: 'zoom2'}
```

instead? Maybe there is a good design pattern for this, dunno.

Comment: What do you mean by `who is calling the method`?

Comment: There might be an *odd* way of doing something like this, but it sounds more like an X/Y problem IMO

Comment: @CertainPerformance not an XY problem in this case - quite literally want to serialize an object differently depending on who/where the serialize call was made.

Comment: @SergioFlores I want a different serialized representation of the object depending on context.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: That doesn’t make it not an XY problem.

Comment: write a function that takes the name of the attribute you want stringified as a param

Comment: `context` in this *context* is pretty vague. It's hard to know what information is available, and where, to influence how the object is stringified. `JSON.stringify` does take an option `replacer` parameter that can be used to filter keys. Maybe there's some way to communicate the context with that.

Comment: @Ry it doesn't mean it's not not an XY problem either :) see my answer

Comment: @AlexanderMills: But it’s not sounding likely that it isn’t and your answer doesn’t do anything to change that. (In fact, if your answer is correct, your question was incorrect, because you solved the problem you *really* had using a method you didn’t allow for. XY.)

Comment: @Ry- I think you are splitting hairs bro, I used the same method in my answer as I did in the question, just with another arg. Please :)

Comment: You asked for a way to detect who was calling `JSON.stringify` in your `toJSON`. Everyone who interacted with the question told you that was probably wrong. It turned out to be that. It’s an XY problem. Read up on the specifics so you can make the appropriate edits when the first comment gets made.

Comment: @Ry- no I asked how to stringify an object differently depending on context, it's cool, we can let it go lol. The title of the OP has not changed :)

Comment: *“is there a way to stringify it differently depending on who is calling JSON.stringify()”*. You post *a lot* of questions, so please step up the quality.

Comment: @Ry- technically I don't have an answer for this question yet b/c the replacer function I have isn't working, so there's room for answer

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you could use the replacer [parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) of the [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function:

> A function that alters the behavior of the stringification process, or an array of String and Number objects that serve as a whitelist for selecting/filtering the properties of the value object to be included in the JSON string. If this value is null or not provided, all properties of the object are included in the resulting JSON string.

Example:

```
const v = {
  foo: 'zoom1',
  bar: 'zoom2'
};

JSON.stringify(v, ['foo']);
// Outputs "{"foo":"zoom1"}

JSON.stringify(v, ['bar']);
// Outputs "{"bar":"zoom2"}

JSON.stringify(v, ['foo', 'bar']);
// Outputs "{"foo":"zoom1", "bar":"zoom2"}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple deprecated methods that allow you to determine who called a particular function: [arguments.callee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee) and [function.caller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller).

However, I would suggest that instead of altering the object you are trying to serialize, or monkey patching a built-in serialization function, you instead just define helper serialization methods that will return the object in different ways (like different views on the same data)

Something like the following idea, if `flat` and `deep` are the two different views you want to return of the object:

```
const myData = {}

const flatSerializer = (data) => {}
const deepSerializer = (data) => {}

const flatString = flatSerializer(myData)
const deepString = deepSerializer(myData)
```

If you want to introduce some function composition, you could also create different ways of representing the data that are passed into the same serialization function.

Using that same example, you might have something like:

```
const myData = {}

const serializer = fn => data => fn(data)
const flat = data => {}
const deep = data => {}

const flatSerialize = serializer(flat)
const deepSerialize = serializer(deep)

const flatString = flatSerialize(myData)
const deepString = deepSerialize(myData)
```

Comment: Won't `arguments.caller` always be `JSON.stringify()`? He wants to know who called `JSON.stringify()`, not who called his `toJSON()` method.

Answer (score 2):

One option could be to use the `replacer` argument to `stringify`. It is a function called with the key and value of each property being stringified in the Object, and if you return `undefined` from it, the property is excluded from stringify result.

You could have a bunch of replacer functions in a library each of which returns undefined for a set of properties you want to exclude i.e. so essentially creating different "views" of the object. Then the caller selects which of the replacers it wants when calling stringify.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The%20replacer%20parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this yet, but I think a custom replacer is the answer, something like this:

```
const result = JSON.stringify(v, (val) => {

   if(val instanceof whatever){
      return {bar: val.bar};
   }

   return val;

});
```